# The Sobolev space $H^s(\mathbb R^n)$ is closed under multiplication when $s>n/2$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Show that if $u,v\in H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for $s>{n\over 2}$, then $uv \in H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and
$$
\|uv\|_{H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)} \le C\|u\|_{H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)} \|v\|_{H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)},
$$
the constant $C$ depending only on $s$ and $n$.

#### Progress

I tried to prove by induction on the order of the derivatives, but to use the inductive hypotheses could not get the term right inequality. My problem is to find the appropriate method to be able to solve actual inequality.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem?

Comment: The truth, I tried to prove by induction on the order of the derivatives, but to use the inductive hypotheses could not get the term right inequality. My problem is to find the appropriate method to be able to solve actual inequality.